# How to Pass null if data is not defined?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Let's say i have 3 columns in the dropdown selection i.e

1. ID = equals, greaterThan, lessThan.
2. Date Filter = equals, greaterThan, lessThan.
3. Name Filter = contains, equals, lessThan.

than i am getting the ID & Name Filter inside the data props, but not Date Filter, because of that i got undefined

```
    <GetFilter title="ID Filter" expression="hello" >
        <RangeLogicFields data={boardFilter.Id} />
      </GetFilter>

      <GetFilter title="Name Filter" expression="hello" >
        <StringLogicFields data={boardFilter.Name} />
      </GetFilter>

      <GetFilter title="StartDate Filter" expression="hello" >
        {/* <DateLogicFields  data= {boardFilter.StartDate  } /> */}
      </GetFilter>
```

i am setting null value inside the state

```
 Id: {
      equals: 0,
      greaterThan: 0,
      greaterThanOrEqual: 0,
      inLists: [],
      lessThan: 0,
      lessThanOrEqual: 0,
      specified: true
    },
    Name: {
      contains: '',
      equals: '',
      inLists: [],
      specified: true
    },
    StartDate: {
      equals: '2020-03-20T02:14:58Z',
      greaterThan: '',
      greaterThanOrEqual: '',
      inLists: [],
      lessThan: '',
      lessThanOrEqual: '',

    },
```

i am unable to check null data kindly help , i am using typescript react

Comment: try this {boardFilter.Id || null} or {boardFilter.Id !== undefined ? boardFilter.Id : null}

Comment: { boardFilter.StartDate ? <DateLogicFields  data= {boardFilter.StartDate  }  /> : null} this is the same but, i want to get the deafult state if data is not defined,

Comment: As per your suggestion ,Cannot read property 'equals' of null, thows error  @FatemehQasemkhani

Comment: {boardFilter.Id !== undefined ? boardFilter.Id : null} just will check the undefined